# How to create multiple rows in Laravel controller by getting data from vuejs component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, controller, resources, axios

I sending an array of object of multiple products by [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). Here is my `confirmPurchases()` method, by this method I'm sending an array to laravel controller.

```
confirmPurchases()
{
    axios
    .post(`/sells/sellProduct/`, this.bags)
    .then( res => {
        console.log(res.data);
    } );
}
```

My sending array is looking like this

```
[
    { product_id: 1 , product_name: "product 1" , quantity: 1 },
    { product_id: 2 , product_name: "product 3" , quantity: 1 },
    { product_id: 3 , product_name: "product 2" , quantity: 1 }
]
```

When I was about to try to create multiple time by Eloquent Model by `foreach` , I get horrible errors

```
public function sellProduct(Request $request)
{
    foreach( $request as $product ){
        Sell::create([
            'product_id' => $product->product_id,
            'sell_price' => $product->sell_price,
            'quantity' => $product->quantity
        ]);
    } 
}
```

Can you suggest me a good way to do this?

Comment: What are the errors? You should post those.

Comment: https://s18.postimg.org/i4vmrhm09/Screenshot_1.png https://s18.postimg.org/6308xckhl/Screenshot_2.png @skribe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$request` variable is not an actual array, so you can't iterate this trough `foreach` in php.

As, at-first `$request` need to make an array then do your business as your wish :)

```
public function sellProduct(Request $request)
{
    $products = json_decode($request->getContent() , true);

    foreach( $products as $product )
    {
        Sell::create([
            'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
            'sell_price' => $product['sell_price'],
            'quantity' => $product['quantity']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this `json_decode($request->getContent(), true)` then `$request` will be actual php array?

Comment: @KingRayhan yess

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

You are foreaching the request object instead of actuall array. What you could do:
Assuming your sending array matches the Seller attributes.

```
$data = request()->get('params');

$data = json_decode($data, true);

Seller::insert($data);
```

`insert()` its used to insert multiple eloquent data at one time

Comment: what is `params` here?